# Node.js, Mongoose function return an error the first time but not the second

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a function which return some elements from my MongoDB database but I have a problem with my variables. It says that one of my variable isn't defined the first time but then if I refresh, the error disappear. So I think it's an error of global variable defined in an inner scope which can't be accessed the first time or something like that.

So here's my code :

```
exports.findQuestion = function findQuestion()
{
    var tabRand = new Array();      // on déclare un nouveau tableau où on va stocker les jets de rand
    var query = boardModel.find(null);      // on cherche toutes les entrées dans la collection 
    query.exec(function (err, tabQuestion) {
    if (err) { throw err;}
    var rep = tabQuestion[0];
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*rep.question.length+1));   // random sur le tableau
    var i = false;
    tabRand[0] = 0;
    while (i == false)
    {
    for(var random in tabRand)      // on vérifie le résultat du rand avec les rand précédents
    {
        if(random != rand)          // si le rand est différent on le garde
        {
            i = true;
            if(tabRand.length-1 == rep.question.length) // si la taille de tabRand est égale à la longueur du tableau de questions de la collection alors on le reinitialise
            {
                tabRand = new Array();
            }
        }
    }
    tabRand.push[rand];     // on ajoute le rand précédent à tabRand
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*rep.question.length+1));   // et on en fait un nouveau
    }
    quest = rep.question[rand-1].quest; // on récupère le resultat attendu
    repJuste = rep.question[rand-1].rep_j;
    repFausse1 = rep.question[rand-1].rep_f1;
    repFausse2 = rep.question[rand-1].rep_f2;
    gainQ = rep.question[rand-1].gain;
    nomTr = rep.question[rand-1].name_t;
    });
return [quest, repJuste, repFausse1, repFausse2, gainQ, nomTr];
}
```

So the first time, it says that quest is not defined but then everything works well ...

PS : Sorry for the half-French, half-English code ^^

Comment: You can't return an asynchronous result from a function, you have to use a callback.

Comment: you might check out the await module (```npm await```). In this way you can effectively wait to return the results from your asynchronous code.

Comment: Johnny : I don't really understand your comment :( 
How can I use a callback to do what I'm trying to do ?

Daniel : I will check the npm await, that seems perfect for what I wanna do.

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem here, you can't return something in a asynchronous function, you should use a callback.

If you want to understand it :

- You do your asynchronous query (and you do something in your callback with the result tabQuestion)
- and your return something but you're not sure your async function is done.

try [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help you manage your asynchronous problems

EDIT:

```
async.parallel([
function(callback){ 
boardModel.find().exec(function (err, tabQuestion) {
    if (err) { throw err;}
    var rep = tabQuestion[0];
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*rep.question.length+1));   // random sur le tableau
    var i = false;
    tabRand[0] = 0;
    while (i == false)
    {
    for(var random in tabRand)      // on vérifie le résultat du rand avec les rand précédents
    {
        if(random != rand)          // si le rand est différent on le garde
        {
            i = true;
            if(tabRand.length-1 == rep.question.length) // si la taille de tabRand est égale à la longueur du tableau de questions de la collection alors on le reinitialise
            {
                tabRand = new Array();
            }
        }
    }
    tabRand.push[rand];     // on ajoute le rand précédent à tabRand
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*rep.question.length+1));   // et on en fait un nouveau
    }
    quest = rep.question[rand-1].quest; // on récupère le resultat attendu
    repJuste = rep.question[rand-1].rep_j;
    repFausse1 = rep.question[rand-1].rep_f1;
    repFausse2 = rep.question[rand-1].rep_f2;
    gainQ = rep.question[rand-1].gain;
    nomTr = rep.question[rand-1].name_t;
    });
    callback(null, quest, repJuste, repFausse1, repFausse2, gainQ, nomTr);
}],
function(err){
    if(err){ 
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.timeEnd('chargement bd');
        socket.emit('event', {'quest': quest, 'repJuste' : repJuste }); //add all your params
    }               
});
```

Comment: I've checked the await and async.js library but I find them very difficult to understand. I find the async even more complicated than the await. 
If someone could explain or provide a simple example on how to use one of these lib, I will be very grateful and happy ^^

Comment: Try something like that, i'll do that in my project with socket.io but you see async.parallel to execute an array of asynchronous function and the final function is the callback which is execute when all the async function are done.
I hope it will be usefull for you (et vive la baguette)

Comment: There is a missing closing accolade in your code for the "function(callback)" and I don't know where to put it. 
Also I have a question, how can I do to use the variable returned by my function through this method. Do I recover them with a socket on the client side ?
But merci for the answers till then ;)

Comment: i put the missing semicolon (before closing the array).
Yes i use [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/) to send the data just make an event in your client-side code and grab them.

Comment: Now I got an error on boardModel.find().exec 
It says cannot call method find of undefined. It's the same when I pass through an intermediate variable "query". Maybe he cannot access to boardModel now ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoose sooo i can't help you for this one :s

Comment: Ok, I will try to find out tomorrow. Thanks for all, Crema ;) If anybody else has an idea maybe, I'm interrested :)

Comment: If I understand well, the use of async.js is not obligatory. So I've try to only use the callbacks to do that but I don't manage to do it neither.